# In Python, why do warnings not appear when using `eval`?

Tags: python, warnings, eval

The following code prints a warning, as expected:

```
>>> import warnings
>>> def f():
...     warnings.warn('Deprecated', DeprecationWarning)
...     print('In function f()')
... 
>>> f()
__main__:2: DeprecationWarning: Deprecated
In function f()
```

However, when using `eval`, the warning message does not appear:

```
>>> eval('f()')
In function f()
```

Why do warnings behave differently in these two situations?

Comment: Im assuming that Eval might be running that function in a mini-instance that does not have the warnings module present, but thats just me guessing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Why do warnings behave differently in these two situations?

They don't. From the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/warnings.html):

> Repetitions of a particular warning for the same source location are
>   typically suppressed.

```
import warnings

def f():
    warnings.warn("dep", DeprecationWarning)
    print('in f')

f()
warnings.resetwarnings()
eval('f()')
```

Or:

```
import warnings

def f():
    warnings.warn("dep", DeprecationWarning)
    print('in f')

# don't call f()
#f()
eval('f()')
```

Both show the warning from the `eval('f()')` call:

```
# with warnings.resetwarnings() between f() and eval('f()')
in f
/home/gir/local/dev/pcws/local/main.py:7: DeprecationWarning: dep
in f
  warnings.warn("dep", DeprecationWarning)
/home/gir/local/dev/pcws/local/main.py:7: DeprecationWarning: dep
  warnings.warn("dep", DeprecationWarning)

# without calling f() directly
/home/gir/local/dev/pcws/local/main.py:5: DeprecationWarning: dep
in f
  warnings.warn("dep", DeprecationWarning)
```